# Print file name of \include{} in the output

Tags: include, jobname

How to print file name that contains word in the `\include{ABC-2100011}` in the PDF output?

Print File name: `\filename` ---> Output should be Print File name: ABC-2100011

Please find MWE file as follows:
Main File name: `Main.tex`
Child file name: `ABC-2100011.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\includeonly{ABC-2100011}

\begin{document}

Print File name: \filename

\include{ABC-2100011}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like you're wanting `\filename` to be the name of the file that's included later on.  Is that correct?  Do you have more than one `\include` in your document?  How should LaTeX handle that?  (If not, why are you using `\includeonly`?)  Would it work to say `\newcommand{\filename}{ABC-2100011} ... \include{\filename}`?

Comment: I want to print file name used in the \inlcude{} or \includeonly{}, which is need to print slug line top of text area through template.

Comment: In my document only one \include{} used, getting file name \includeonly{} also fine.